# Same interface from multiple type

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have an interface, and there are some implementations for this. Each implementation belongs to some type.
I want that when I'm using autowired I would able to get all the implementation of the certain type. How can I do it?

```
public interface someInterface{}

public class impl1OfType1 implements someInterface{}
public class impl2OfType1 implements someInterface{}

public class impl1OfType2 implements someInterface{}
public class impl2OfType2 implements someInterface{}

public class someClass{
   @autowired
   public someClass(List<someInterface> interfaceList){}

}
```

I want to get only `impl1OfType1` and `impl2OfType1`. And not all the implementation.
And at other place I want to get only `impl1OfType2` and `impl2OfType2`.

more concrete example -

```
    public interface EntityCreator{
      createEntity();
    }

    @Component
    public class DogCreator implements entityCreator{}
    @Component
    public class CatCreator implements entityCreator{}
    @Component
    public class CarCreator implements entityCreator{}
    @Component
    public class TruckCreator implements entityCreator{}

    @Component
    public class AnimalsFactory{
       @Autowired
       public AnimalsFactory(List<EntityCreator> creators){}

    }
```

Comment: a class *`implements`* an interface, not `extends` it

Comment: Please read about Java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase always!

Comment: Given what you posted, you should get nothing at all since none of the classes is annotated with `@Component`. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, otherwise all we can do is guess what the problem might be.

Comment: @eliranyosef Please be accurate with the edits, 2 `CarCreator`s and `@autowired` make little sense

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be using `@Qualifier`.

```
@Component
@Qualifier("place1")
class Impl1OfType2 implements SomeInterface {}

@Component
@Qualifier("place1")
class Impl2OfType2 implements SomeInterface {}

@Service
class SomeClass {
    @Autowired
    public SomeClass(@Qualifier("place1") List<SomeInterface> interfaceList) {
        System.out.println(interfaceList);
    }
}
```

I slightly changed the names to adhere to the Java convention. They are still a bit awkward and contextless.

### UPDATE

You might use generics, Spring is good at dealing with them. For instance, it will inject only `DogCreator` and `CatCreator` into a `List<EntityCreator<Animal>>`.

```
interface Animal {}
interface Machine {}

interface EntityCreator<T> {}

@Component
class DogCreator implements EntityCreator<Animal> {}
@Component
class CatCreator implements EntityCreator<Animal> {}

@Component
class CarCreator implements EntityCreator<Machine> {}
@Component
class TruckCreator implements EntityCreator<Machine> {}

@Component
class AnimalsFactory {
    @Autowired
    public AnimalsFactory(List<EntityCreator<Animal>> creators) { }
}
```

### UPDATE 2

You could write marker interfaces which would break down existing implementations into logical groups.

```
interface AnimalCreator {}

interface EntityCreator<T> {}

@Component
class DogCreator implements EntityCreator, AnimalCreator {}
@Component
class CatCreator implements EntityCreator, AnimalCreator {}

@Component
class AnimalsFactory {
    @Autowired
    public AnimalsFactory(List<AnimalCreator> creators) {
        System.out.println(creators);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution I had think about this idea, but I don't want that each one who will create implementation to interface should add qualifier. How can I do it?

Comment: @eliranyosef Spring operates on presented meta-information, I don't think there's any different to tell Spring filter out candidates for autowiring.

Comment: @eliranyosef you may write another interface which would be shared by the interfaces that are supposed to be used in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

If you correct your code with above comments and I understand your problem,  I assume this can be a way to solve your issue.

```
public interface Someinterface<T extends someType> {}
public class someType{}
public class Type1 extends someType{}
public class Type2 extends someType{}

public class TypedInterface1 implements Someinterface<Type1> {}
public class TypedInterface2 implements Someinterface<Type2> {}

public class someClass{
   @Autowired
   public someClass(List<TypedInterface1> interfaceList){}
}
```

Let me know if I answered your question.

Comment: your answer absolutely makes no sense to me. Compare your code to OP's. I downvoted.

Comment: In OP post, the type cannot be deduced because of multiple implementations of Someinterface. In my solution however Type inference is not a problem. So DI framework should have no issue injecting the correct implementation. However I have just begin in JAVA from C++ and may have misunderstood something.